# How to add items to array in react

Tags: reactjs

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [name,setName] = useState("");
  var myArray = [];
  const handleAdd = () => {
    myArray = [...myArray,name]
    setName("")
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder="type a name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>add</button> 
      <button onClick={() => console.log(myArray)}>test</button>
      {myArray.map((n) => {
        return <h2>{n}</h2> 
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

OnClick it isn't adding the name to the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is how you "push" to an array with useState

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([])
setArray(previous => [...previuous, newItem])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `state` for your array and set that `state` to see the changes reflected:

```
export default function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
    const handleAdd = () => {
        setMyArray([...myArray, name]);
        setName('');
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input
                placeholder="type a name"
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={handleAdd}>add</button>
            <button onClick={() => console.log(myArray)}>test</button>
            {myArray.map((n) => {
                return <h2>{n}</h2>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also set the state of `myArr` to be an empty array initially, making it easier to manipulate the subsequent state of that array. The `onClick` event handler does not fire the `handleAdd` function, for some reason, it only resets the form and does not provide any state. To submit the form and materialize the state, we can also use the `onSubmit` event handler instead of `onClick`. In the same way, we can use the `name` state as a `value/prop` for the `name input`, which will be used by the `onChange` handler.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [myArr, setMyArr] = useState([])

const submit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  setMyArr(myArr.concat(name))
  setName('')
}

//console.log(myArr)
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <div>
         <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
         <input
           placeholder="type a name"
           type="text"
           value={name}
           onChange={({ target }) => setName(target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      {myArr.map((arr, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{arr}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
   </div>
  )
 }

export default App
```

I have a proclivity of inserting items on an array using `concat`.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
// ...
const App = () => {

// ...

const [myArr, setMyArr] = useState([])

// somewhere on your event handler e.g. Submit handler
setMyArr(myArr.concat(name))

// ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

  const Final = () => {
   const [input,setInput]=useState("");
  const[array,setArray]=useState([]);

   const handleClick=(e)=>{
     setArray([...array,input]);
      setInput("");
     }
         const Rushabh=(e)=>{
          if(e.key==='Enter'){
          handleClick();
          }
           }
       return (
         <div>
              <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Name" value= 
         {input} onChange= 
           {(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)} onKeyDown={Rushabh}/>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>

            <p>{array.map((e,index)=>{
              return (
                  <p key={index}>{e}</p>
              )
            })}</p>
           </div>
          )
          }

          export default Final
```